# coldfusion REST service, 404 not found

Tags: rest, coldfusion

I cannot seem to get my REST service to work... I get a 404 when I call the URL.

Im running Win 7, CF 10 developer, Apache webserver. I've developed on this for years, so the setup works - but this is my first go at REST services thru CF... I mention that because CF is working, the dir and webserver are working etc.

Directory looks like this

C:\wwwroot\restTest

CODE - saved as "obj1.cfc" - ( Note: I've tried restpath with and without the / )

```
<cfcomponent restpath="/restTest" rest="true" >

    <cffunction name="getMethod" access="remote" returntype="String" httpmethod="GET" >

        <cfreturn "this is a string returned" />

    </cffunction>

</cfcomponent>
```

The coldfusion ADMIN setup looks like this

```
Root path: 'C:\wwwroot\restTest'
Service Mapping: 'test'
```

I'm using the service mapping because I don't have an associated application name - no Application.cfc - I was trying to keep this super simple.

I get a green 'success' message when I set that path

Browse to -

```
127.0.0.1/rest/test/restTest/
```

result - 404

What am I doing wrong? It is my understanding that "/rest/" is a default mapped path in CF for routing the service - I may be wrong, but I know I read it somewhere - and the examples all use it. I also believe I can change that either in the admin or in some XML file...

Comment: Have you tried removing the trailing `/` from your URL? That's the only difference i can see between your code and the example code on Adobe's site. You may also want to try using CF's built-in webserver and bypass Apache temporarily, just to isolate another variable. When I played with CF's REST implementation, I did find it very fiddly to get things running happily

Comment: ya - tried wo /.. havent tried CFs weserver yet - good idea

Answer (score 2):

Turns out - Apache needed this line added to the host (or globally in the config)

```
JkMountFile "C:/ColdFusion10/config/wsconfig/1/uriworkermap.properties"
```

Once I added that... all was good.